# Why doesn't Windows 10 task scheduler require administrative permissions to configure a task to run elevated?

Tags: windows-10, uac, task-scheduler

[image]

It seems that I don't need administrator permission (it did not prompt for UAC control) to configure a task to run elevated. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling the **Run with highest privileges** option does not guarantee a task will be run with elevated permissions.

For a task to actually run with elevated permissions, the user account configured to launch the task must be a member of the Administrators group. And the only way to configure an admin user to be the one to launch a task is if you know the account's password. Therefore only an administrator can enable this option and produce the intended effect.

If a user is not a member of the administrators group, enabling this option has no effect. Therefore there's no reason to prohibit a standard user from enabling the option.

Comment: Then, if I'm an intruder, and wrote a script to enable my virus in task scheduler, isn't it dangerous if end user runs this script without knowing it will run an elevated suspicious task in the next bootup?

Comment: The only way you can configure a task to run *for another user* is if you know that user's password. If a malicious user knows this there's no point in tricking then into running a task, you could just logon and run it for them.

Comment: I tried to used another account and doing the same procedure, it DOES require another Administrator account authentication for the task to have "Run with highest privileges, hence I assume there is protection if it runs from a non-administrators account.

Comment: I'm thinking about a scenario: e.g. usually when I downloaded an utility software from internet, if it does not prompt UAC, I suppose it's safe, cuz it won't require elevated permission.  However, with this task scheduler, I suppose it's possible that an hacker provided a "tool(malware)", which schedules a task at next boot, with "highest privilege" of my account, but does not prompt an UAC, therefore I won't know it requires administrator permission

Comment: @chrisky this is why UAC does not mean safaty at all. There are many ways to bypass UAC and MS is not  going to fix them. Don't run anything untrusted as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, but you do need elevation. It’s just that, for your convenience, by default, built-in Microsoft Management Console files are started with admin rights automatically and without any prompt. This applies but is not limited to:

- Disk Management
- Computer Management
- Services
- Hyper-V Manager

You can easily check in Task Manager, just enable the “Elevated” column.

If you forcibly (`__APPCOMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER`) start MMC without admin, you will find that you cannot save the task with the checkbox enabled: A prompt for your password will appear, followed by this message:

[image: error message]

If you try with elevation, you will not be prompted for your credentials and the task can be saved.

This does not result in a security vulnerability (hopefully) because only special applications start without a prompt and lower-privileged software cannot “remote control” these applications.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you did not get the UAC prompt doesn't mean there won't be any.

The moment you create the task it will evaluate if you have the rights. If you don't a popup will be shown asking you for your credentials, and it will expect credentials from a user that has administrative privileges.

The `Run with highest privileges` will run under the SYSTEM user, so in any case, administrative rights are required to create the task. The creation happens when you press OK.

Comment: When I created the task it did not ask for UAC either. I am administrators group, but I suppose when I create that task it should ask for elevation but it did not, which confuses me...

Comment: *The Run with highest privileges will run under the SYSTEM user*... Not correct. The user used to launch the task is specified separately. This option runs the task with the highest privileges the specified user account *actually has*, which may or may not be administrative privileges.